# Converting milliseconds to pixels

Tags: android, kotlin, math, pixel

I'm building an EPG layout from scratch and I want to calculate the width of the cells for the programs based on their runtime. I thought the best way to go about this is converting them to pixels and setting the width of the item to that. But it's coming up very small (maybe 5pixels at most). Is there a way to achieve this? Even better if I can use DP instead of PX. Below is the formula I'm using to do the conversion

```
fun convertMillisecondsToPx(millis: Float, context: Context): Float =
        millis * pxPerMinConstant(context) / TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)
```

with `pxPerMinConstant(context)`

```
  fun pxPerMinConstant(context: Context): Float =
       convertDpToPixel(context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.epg_width_one_min), context)
```

and `convertDpToPixel`

```
fun convertDpToPixel(dp: Float, context: Context): Float =
        applyDimension(COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.resources.displayMetrics)
```

and **dimen_epg_width_one_min** = **2dp**

Comment: What does `convertDpToPixel()` look like? How are you getting the value of `millis` that you pass to `convertMillisecondsToPx()`?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Sorry, forgot to add. ```convertDpToPixel``` is now in the question

And I'm getting the value by having the endTime of the show minus the startTime which is from the API in ```mills```

Comment: `resources.getDimension` returns your dimension already converted to pixel units, so you are converting it twice. But I would expect that to make the number too big, not too small, because virtually all devices have more than `mdpi` density.

Comment: I always get 0 as the return even if I just use resource.getDimension.